# Using XML files for PHP web app

Tags: php, xml, backend

I'm thinking of using XML for storing users content on my web app. I am a php newbie and don't know much about how I would do this.

The content is private to the user, not shared public or for passwords or anything. So I was wondering how I can create and edit xml files on the backend part of the server, privately accessed by PHP like what it does with mySQL.

My questions are: 1) Is it possible 2) If so, how would I do it using php etc.

Comment: "I'm thinking of using XML for storing users content" - you should probably re-think that. If XML, why not JSON or SQL?

Comment: Why the hang-up on XML?  It seems like you are just using this for storage of data or flat file data serialization.  For this purpose XML is very verbose, and maybe more painful to deal with depending on how you need to access that information. Really the answer to your question can not really be answered until you understand how the data will need to be accessed (i.e. will you just get all of it at once and load into an object, do you only need to retrieve certain bits of data at a time, etc.).

Comment: Question 3 in your list above is very confusing - it's a laundry list of technologies, and it's not clear why you even mention them?  Is your question how to use XML in PHP, or is it really how should you store data in a webapp?

Comment: sqlite or BDB might be appropriate choices in a context like this

Comment: There is a vast amount of varying data for the things the user creates. That's why I didn't want to use a database or JSON.

Comment: @ernie Somewhat both. I'm saying that if it's possible to use xml in php, then how to use it and if not, should I use a different technology that may be easier or more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put all xml files in a folder that is not accessible via the web, so outside of your document root. Alternatively, you can use .htaccess to restrict access to that folder.

For reading and writing those xml files from your directory, you can use [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). You don't need anything else despite pure php and some xml processing.

This should get you started ;).

Comment: Excellent answer.  I didn't know this existed.

Comment: Is htaccess very secure for this type of thing?

Comment: @user1858108 I don't see a problem with .htaccess, if you put `deny from all`.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it is possible. by making your xml in php files format which output xml formatted tags after PHP authentication. The PHP files will be created dynamically using PHP filesystem functions and will be modified also, for each users in a specified folder(s) for your users.

Comment: Good idea, but I think I might do it a more conventional way.